# Why would a call to Hashmap.containsKey() be 100 times slower in deployed environment vs local?

Tags: java

Same code, same data.  HashMap has around 40K entries, keyed by a String.  Timing was determined with System.nanoTime().

Local:

```
2015-08-21 12:46:09,958 DEBUG PERFORMANCE_ISSUE:55 - containsKey took 44336
```

Deployed:

```
2015-08-21 11:17:43,901 DEBUG PERFORMANCE_ISSUE:55 - containsKey took 4657210
```

I'm thinking something with GC or swapping, but was looking for other ideas...

Comment: You can analyze GC  using VisualVm  what is the difference between these 2 systems?

Comment: Is this consistently slower or just randomly?

Comment: What is the difference in cofig of local and deployed env ?

Comment: How did you do the timing? [Java microbenchmarking is non-trivial!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/4125191).

Comment: BTW You can have a 4 ms jitter on your system without a GC.  The OS can cause this much delay esp if you don't have bare metal machine.

Comment: Check the amount of memory assigned to Java (`-Xmx`). If the number is low on your server, Java may be running GC all the time. Try logging GC activity with `-Xloggc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following:

- If both are running on same hardware. Check for the memory allocated to JVM. A very low memory can cause a good delay.
- If they are on different machines (hardware) then check for currently used Memory and Processor which can affect the time to run a program.
- Although it should not be an issue but you can also check for the java version in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Boy do I feel dumb.  It wasn't the same code at all.  The local code (fast) was using a java.util.HashMap, and, due to a situation I won't go into here, the deployed code (slow) was actually ending up with a scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$MapWrapper .

So copying the values from the MapWrapper into a real HashMap before invoking the slow algorithm has solved the issue.

I appreciate all of the suggested answers anyway.  SO is a wonderful community.  I'm tempted to delete this post but will leave it up in case it helps anyone else in future.